# LDAP query missing attributes

Tags: python, ldap

1. I'm using the [ldap3](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/) python library to make LDAP calls. I have it set to query all attributes and all operational attributes. If I query a user I get back ~80 attributes.
2. My colleague made calls using ADSIedit and powershell, and it returned ~120 attributes for a single user.
3. The ~80 ldap3 results contains attributes that the ~120 ADSI edit attributes didn't, even though the ADSI edit result has more.

Which leads to my question.

What is causing the disparity between results, and what can I do to get all the attributes I need under one roof. From what I read it looks like I'll need to query multiple servers to get all the information I'll need. Is that assumption correct? Can anyone suggest the best approach? Thanks.

Comment: What multiple servers? And did your colleague use the same account you did?

Comment: It could be possible that ADSI use on some operation some control which tells AD to expand the DN contained in attributes of the user to the value (IE nested group, etc)